# Ошибка SyntaxError: Invalid destructuring assignment target

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid destructuring assignment target

Я просто не понимаю почему слайдер не работает. Объясните, пожалуйста

```js
$(document).ready(function({
      $('.slider-inner').slick();
    });
```

```css
.slider__item {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  min-height: 550px;
}

.slider__item::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.47);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.slider__item-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 550px;
}

.slider-title {
  flex-grow: 2;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.slider__text {
  color: #000;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.slider-description {
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:300,400,500|Playfair+Display:400,700&display=swap&subset=cyrillic" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.12.0-1/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">

<main class="main">
  <section class="main-slider">
    <div class="slider-inner">
      <div class="slider-item" style="background-image: url(img/slider/slider-1.jpg);">
        <div class="slider-item__content">
          <div class="slider-head">
            <h1 class="slider-title">Заголовок</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="slider-text">
            <p class="slider-description"> Описание</p>
            <p class="price"> Цена</p>
          </div>
          <button class="cta"> Купить </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="slider-item" style="background-image: url(img/slider/slider-  2.jpg);">
        <div class="slider-item__content">
          <div class="slider-head">
            <h1 class="slider-title">Заголовок</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="slider-text">
            <p class="slider-description"> Описание</p>
            <p class="price"> Цена </p>
          </div>
          <button class="cta"> Купить </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</main>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Для начала подправить тут `$(document).ready(function({` --> `$(document).ready(function() {` И описать подробнее, что значит "не работает".

Comment: @РустамГимранов, если подправить, то и ошибки не будет :)

Comment: Опечатка в строке `$(document).ready(function({` - не хватает закрывающей круглой скобки:  `$(document).ready(function() {`